# How to make a worldboard extend 1 block everyday

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make a minecraft survival world where the world boarder extends 1 block everyday. I tried using command blocks and daylight sensors but got confused.

Comment: I want to know to make it widen every night. That question just has it extend. I would like to know how to set it up what command where do i put the day light sensor